# Convertir string a decimal en oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Intento convertir un numero decimal contenido dentro de un string a decimal y obtengo el siguiente error:

Base de datos Oracle

> ORA-01722: número no válido
>   01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
>   *Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
>   *Action:   Specify a valid number.

Código SQL:

```
TO_NUMBER('5.0') AS numero

CAST('5.0' AS NUMBER) AS numero
```

Comment: Puedes poner la sentencia entera?

Answer (score 1):

Andres

Tu problema es que pasas el string del número con punto '.' y no con coma ',', tus funciones de conversión están ok, pero debes reemplazar el punto por coma antes.

```
SELECT 
TO_NUMBER (
REPLACE('5.33','.',',')
) AS NUMERO1,

CAST(
REPLACE('5.33','.',',')
AS NUMBER) 
AS NUMERO2
```

Answer (score 0):

Si este es el número en cuestión: `01722. 00000`, lo puede reconocer como inválido debido a que hay un espacio entre el punto y el cero que le continua. Antes de convertir, usa una función REPLACE donde reemplaces el espacio por un caracter en blanco. Ejemplo:

```
CAST(REPLACTE(miNumero, ' ', '') as NUMBER)
```